# Aliasing a sub-expression within a python expression

Tags: python

Can I temporarily alias an expression, within another expression? Such a thing is possibly within, say, SQL, where expressions can be extremely long, but I'm not familiar with a way to do this in Python. I'm not really concerned with whether I *should* do this, I am more curious as to whether it is possible within Python syntax.

```
dict_a = {'p1c1': [0, 520],
 'p1c2': [400, 740],
 'p1c3': [600, 800],
 'p1c4': [600, 800],
 'p1c5': [660, 960],
 'p1c6': [760, 1200],
 'p2c1': [400, 900],
 'p2c2': [600, 920],
 'p2c3': [700, 1040],
 'p2c4': [700, 1040],
 'p2c5': [780, 1060],
 'p2c6': [800, 1160],
 'p3c1': [800, 1400],
 'p3c2': [1150, 1450],
 'p3c3': [1220, 1600],
 'p3c4': [1220, 1600],
 'p3c5': [1350, 1800],
 'p3c6': [1580, 2000]}
```

Original Expression:

```
dict_b = [dict_a[key][1] - dict_a[key][0] for key in dict_a.keys()]
```

Desired:

```
dict_b = [(r[1] - r[0]) with dict_a[key] as r for key in dict_a.keys()]
```

or something along those lines

Comment: No, but you can sometimes use assignment expressions, i.e. the "walrus operator" to achieve similar things

Answer (score 1):

For your particular use case, you can use `.values()` instead of `.keys()`:

```
dict_b = [r[1] - r[0] for r in dict_a.values()]
```

And if you need both the key and value, use `.items()`. And in other contexts, Python often has convenience functions that will allow similar things, such as `enumerate()` for iterating over both the indexes and values of sequences.

In cases where there is no such shortcut, just use a regular `for` loop so you can assign intermediate variables. Here's how you would rewrite your list comprehension as a loop.

```
for key in dict_a:
    r = dict_a[key]
    dict_b.append(r[1] - r[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Only way to accomplish this that I am aware of is using walrus operator in Python 3.8+. It's not exactly what you're looking for but is similar.

```
dict_b = [r[1] - r[0] for key in dict_a.keys() if (r := dict_a.get(key))]
```

Comment: Using the `if` clause just seems wrong for this. And of course it won't work if the value is falsey, although you could change it to `if (r := dict_a[key]) or True` to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to. You only use the key to get the value, but you can iterate over the values directly.

```
dict_b = [v[1] - v[0] for v in dict_a.values()]
```

If you *do* need the keys, then you can iterate over both in tandem.

```
dict_b = {k: v[1] - v[0] for k, v in dict_a.items()}
```